# How to disable Kibana's periodic request to ElasticSerach

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I went over all kibana.yml time-related values and added zeros (increased them).
Still ElasticSearch gets request each some seconds. How to disable it?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The flag is elasticsearch.healthCheck.delay which is in kibana.yml